# How can I get enum possible values in a MySQL database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql Select Enum Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644220/mysql-select-enum-values)

I have set up a coloumn in `Mysql`:

type: `ENUM`

`Length/Values: '01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12'`

I'm trying to retrive those values from the DB:

I found another post with the same question but my code didn't work

```
$type = $mysqli->query( "SHOW COLUMNS FROM {$tableName} WHERE Field = 'type'" )->fetch_object()->Type;
        preg_match('/^enum\((.*)\)$/', $type, $matches);
        foreach( explode(',', $matches[1]) as $value )
        {
             $enum[] = trim( $value, "'" );
        }
        return $enum;
```

I get type `Text` Insted of `ENUM`

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644220/mysql-select-enum-values]
This is not new question, take a look.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644220/mysql-select-enum-values

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should parse information from `information_schema`.`columns` table -

```
SELECT
  column_type
FROM
  information_schema.columns
WHERE
  table_schema = 'your_schema' AND table_name = 'your_table' AND column_name = 'your_column'
```

...another query -

```
SELECT
  TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM TRIM(LEADING 'enum' FROM column_type))) column_type
FROM
  information_schema.columns
WHERE
  table_schema = 'your_schema' AND table_name = 'your_table' AND column_name = 'your_column';
```

There will be something like this - `enum('01','02','03')`. Parse this string in the php-application.

Comment: Do not forget to add the value `''` which is implicitly present in every enum in MySQL. Or `NULL`, if the field is nullable.