# mysql query to display all the enum values created for a column named department?

Tags: mysql, enums

I have a basic table named employees, with the following columns:

```
user_id PK
first_name
last_name
department enum('accounts', 'sales', 'marketing', 'customer support','billing', 'logistics', 'production') NULL is default.
project_history
email
password SHA1
registration_date
```

So far ive created the database and it contains one table, 'employees'.  As you can see from above its a very simple straight forward table.

I want a quick and easy to to run an sql query in phpMyAdmin's sql editor so I can easily see what enum values/options are available for department. I was intrigued as I wanted to remember what values were created, the only way I am able to see these is by going to structure in phpmyadmin.

Surely there is an sql query I can run to very quickly see the enum values set for department ?

If so I just wanted to know what it was.

There is no need to share the mysql database or the table users as its running locally under wampserver and you can go by what ive provided above.

I expect the query to return something similar to the below:

```
department
---------------
NULL - 0
accounts - 1
sales - 2
marketing - 3
customer support - 4
billing - 5
logistics - 6
production - 7
```

either way, i just want to see the enum values assigned to column department irrespective of how its shown. Can it be done via an sql query cos im very certain it can.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why [`enum` is generally a terrible choice](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) for a column type. You've defined a column and then stored actual values in that column. Instead a proper table called `department` with columns `id | department_name` that has RI to your existing table would be a much more effective schema. It would allow you to add more values in the future without performing an `ALTER table` and it would allow you to quickly query your department names: `SELECT department_name, id FROM departments ORDER BY id;`.

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155322/how-can-i-get-enum-possible-values-in-a-mysql-database-using-php)

Comment: it's possible in pure SQL code, but very complex as you will have to write trickly SQL.. i have to agree with @JNevill here..

Comment: Well the question close before i could post a MySQL only answer as the duplicate includes/used PHP.. For reasons like this i wished i had a gold badge to reopen questions without casting a reopen vote..  Anny how the MySQL only approach https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ATtmqDd5b8jWLCAxueW4e/2

Comment: @Martin you can reopen the question as Raymond has a MySQL only answer

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Done

Comment: @RaymondNijland you can post the answer now

Comment: JNevil's answer was for me, the best.

You were right in what you said,  a seperate table called departments with Dept_ID would work best instead of an enum type column.  I can't believe I overlooked that heh

Comment: totally agree, i've edited mine answer to have the link which @JNevill provided

Answer (score 3):

> This answer is meant for educational purposes, as the 
>   [suggestion](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) provived by  JNevill  in the comments above makes more sense to do

This is possible in pure MySQL code but you will have to write tricky SQL.

Part of the answer includes a SQL number generator

```
SELECT 
 (@number := @number + 1) AS number
FROM (    
  SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10
) AS record_1
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @number := 0 ) AS init_user_param
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ATtmqDd5b8jWLCAxueW4e/2)

The other part is getting the enum as comma seperated string and knowing the number of items.

**Query**

```
SELECT
 REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
      REPLACE(COLUMN_TYPE, 'enum(', '')
      , ')'
      , ''
   )
   , "'"
   , ''
 ) AS comma_separated
 , LENGTH(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(COLUMN_TYPE, 'enum(', '')
        , ')'
        , ''
     )
     , "'"
     , ''
    )   
   ) - LENGTH(REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(COLUMN_TYPE, 'enum(', '')
        , ')'
        , ''
     )
     , "'"
     , ''
    ), ',', '')) + 1 AS number_of_items

FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
   TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
 AND
   TABLE_NAME = 'test'
 AND
   COLUMN_NAME = 'department'
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ATtmqDd5b8jWLCAxueW4e/4)

The last part is knowing how to separate comma separated values..

```
SELECT 
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       'accounts,sales,marketing,customer support,billing,logistics,production'
     , ','
     , 1)
   ,
   ','
   , -1
 )
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ATtmqDd5b8jWLCAxueW4e/7)

When you look in the demo you notice a number which increments to get the next item. 
Now you know why i need to use a sql number generator.

**All magic tricks (parts) combined**

```
SELECT
  number
 , SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(comma_separated, ',', number), ',', -1)

FROM (

SELECT 
 (@number := @number + 1) AS number
FROM (    
  SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10
) AS record_1
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @number := 0 ) AS init_user_param

) AS sql_number_generator
CROSS JOIN (

SELECT
 REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
      REPLACE(COLUMN_TYPE, 'enum(', '')
      , ')'
      , ''
   )
   , "'"
   , ''
 ) AS comma_separated
 , LENGTH(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(COLUMN_TYPE, 'enum(', '')
        , ')'
        , ''
     )
     , "'"
     , ''
    )   
   ) - LENGTH(REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(COLUMN_TYPE, 'enum(', '')
        , ')'
        , ''
     )
     , "'"
     , ''
    ), ',', '')) + 1 AS number_of_items

FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
   TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
 AND
   TABLE_NAME = 'test'
 AND
   COLUMN_NAME = 'department'


) AS a
WHERE
 number BETWEEN 0 AND number_of_items
```

**Result**

```
| number | SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(comma_separated, ',', number), ',', -1) |
| ------ | --------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 1      | accounts                                                                    |
| 2      | sales                                                                       |
| 3      | marketing                                                                   |
| 4      | customer support                                                            |
| 5      | billing                                                                     |
| 6      | logistics                                                                   |
| 7      | production                                                                  |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ATtmqDd5b8jWLCAxueW4e/8)

Performance might be different between MySQL versions and or if the MySQL version caches the `information_schema.COLUMNS` in memory or [optimisations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-optimization.html) exists to access `information_schema` .. 
Also performance depends offcource off the number of existing columns on the complete server.

Comment: my goodness there was no way in the world, I was going to write all that code to achieve what I was looking to achieve : ))

Excellent work though Raymond ;-)

Comment: @ManojKumar this could also be one of the reasons why you should avoid using enum like JNevill also suggested yesterday.

Comment: This is beautiful. It's ugly beyond belief, but beautiful.

Comment: meh,  i mean yeah its OKAY and stuff, but like, i wrote stuff that was as long winded as Raymonds above code in my final year uni days in php,  and i dread to think I'd need to turn back to that code again to achieve anything in 2019 : ))