# Trying to pull enum values from database to store in selection menu php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to pull enum values from database however, i'm only getting a empty selection menu. Could I get some assistance please

```
<?php

include('connectdb.php');

$tableName = 'firefighterinfo';
$columnName = 'status';


echo "<select name=\"$columnName\">";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 'ENUM' FROM `fbmsdatabase`.`firefighterinfo` WHERE `status`='$columnName'") or die (mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$enumList = explode(",", str_replace("'", "", substr($row['ENUM'], 5, (strlen($row['ENUM'])-6))));

foreach($enumList as $value)
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';

echo "</select>";

?>
```

---

```
<label for="Status">Status</label>
  <?php require_once('php/enum_status.php'); ?>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644220/mysql-select-enum-values

Comment: i keep getting Resource id#8 when i include that code

Comment: run query `SELECT column_type FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'MyTable' AND column_name = 'MyColumn';` (put yout table names); then `fetch_array()`; then use the code in solution to `$fetched['column_type']`. this should work.

Comment: This is what I did:   echo "<select name=\"$columnName\">";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT 'ENUM' FROM `fbmsdatabase`.`firefighterinfo` WHERE `status`='$columnName'") or die (mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $result = str_replace(array("enum('", "')", "''"), array('', '', "'"), $result);
$arr = explode("','", $result);


foreach($arr as $value)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}
    
echo "</select>";@user15