# How do I get the enum data type name using a Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, enums

I want to get the name of the `enum` type:

```
Column Name = "Category"
Data Type = "enum"
```

and the enum type contains the following values:

> "test1","test2","test3"

I want to generate a query, which returns me:

> "test1","test2","test3"

How can I do that ?

Comment: Is this concerning MySQL?

Comment: not really; I just want to make a query, which returns me that values

Comment: But are you using MySQL? The enum data type isn't generally available in standard SQL, so in order to answer we need to know what database system you are using.

Comment: Then this might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644220/mysql-select-enum-values

Comment: i find a solution:  SHOW COLUMNS FROM photos LIKE 'category'

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution: `SHOW COLUMNS FROM photos LIKE 'category'`